# Ansible: Evaluate value of var inside parentheses

Tags: ansible

This might be a trivial or a duplicate question, but i seem to have exhausted my search and unable to properly frame a query to search, and so here i am with the question.

How to evaluate a value of a variable inside parentheses.

Below is my vars file

```
patch_version: 6.4
patch_list:
  patch_type1:
    6.4:
      id: 123
      feature: 123
```

And below is the how i am trying to evaluate

`{{ patch_list.patch_type1.{{ patch_version }}.id }}`

Unfortunately, there is a number with a decimal point in it, and that's giving me headache.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the attribute into the brackets. For example

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ patch_list.patch_type1[patch_version].id }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": "123"
```

Comment: Geting the error "The error was: 'list object' has no attribute '6.4'"

Comment: The data from your vars file and my task work as expected. Either you don't use your vars file, or you don't use my task (or both). The problem might be the wrong attribute in your example. "1" is missing in `patch_list.patch_type`. The expression should be `patch_list.patch_type1` if it should work with your vars file.

Comment: Thank you so much, got it working. I was struggling with this since almost 2 hours.